# How to make specific props non-nullable in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type:

```
type Item = {
  cost: number | null
  name: string
  date: string | null
  rating: number | null
}
```

Is there a way in TS to create a type based on `Item`, which would have `date` and `rating` `NonNullable`? I could do something like this:

```
  type FullItem = Omit<Item, 'date' | 'rating'> & {
    date: NonNullable<Item['date']>
    rating: NonNullable<Item['rating']>
  }
```

but it seems a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok, I just came up with a solution it seems:

```
type RequiredNotNull<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[P]>
}

type Ensure<T, K extends keyof T> = T & RequiredNotNull<Pick<T, K>>

type Item = {
  cost: number | null
  name: string
  date: string | null
  rating: number | null
}

type FullItem = Ensure<Item, 'rating' | 'date'>
```

Comment: I would only add a `Required` within ensure, otherwise optional properties will still show undefined.

`& Required<RequiredNotNull<Pick<T, K>>>`

Comment: @colemars You have no idea how much time I spent trying to get rid of this error! This should be added to the answer

Comment: @sayandcode I'm glad that the comment above saved you time! while it certainly provides value to some users, the original question I posted does not mention optionality, only nullability

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `Omit`:

```
type FullItem = Item & {
    date: NonNullable<Item["date"]>;
    rating: NonNullable<Item["rating"]>;
}
```

or of course, if you don't mind repeating the types:

```
type FullItem = Item & {
    date: string;
    rating: number;
}
```

If you changed `Item` later such that the types didn't match, the result would be a member with `never` which I'm guessing would fairly quickly show up and get dealt with. :-)

Comment: I don't want to repeat the types, plus in my case, they get more complicated in some situations

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko - Yeah, fair enough.